# Transforming a polynomial into the polynomial $3^{-1}s^3-z s$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, asymptotics

I am trying to derive asymptotics for the Laguerre polynomial and I ended up with a polynomial

$$\exp(
(c_0-c_1\lambda) s+c_2s^2
+c_3 s^3
+\mathcal{O}(N^{-1/3})
)
$$

Now my goal is to bring the polynomial in the $\exp$-function into the $\frac{s^3}{3}-\lambda s$ form.

I tried to apply the cubic transformation method but the computation gets heavy and complicated, so I don't think this will lead me anywhere. Is there a way to transform the polynomial?

Comment: I think what you're asking for is this: You have a polynomial in the exponential expressed in terms of $s$ and what you want is to re-express it in terms of $s^3 - zs$, correct? If so my guess is that the latter will be a power series rather than a simple polynomial.

Comment: @Aruralreader Yes correct. A power series wouldn't help me much though. There is a method called the "cubic transformation method" which can be found in the paper "An extension of the method of steepest descents" by Chester/Ursell/Friedman which deals with this problem but in my case it gets quite complicated to compute so I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Couldn't you perform a change of variables $s\to a(s/N^{1/3})+b$ for appropriate $a,b$ so you can  kill the $s^2$ term and rescale the $s^3$ term but also get the overall $N$ term for steepest descent?   This will of course change the integrand $f(s)$ which may have to be included in the steepest descent procedure.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I am not seeing this. So we make $s \to (as + b)$ and then have to choose $a$ and $b$ such that $N^{1/3}2^{4/3}\alpha((as)^2 +2asb+b^2)=0$?

Comment: And I forgot the $(as+b)^3 = a^3 s^3 + 3 a^2 b s^2 + 3 a b^2 s + b^3$. Then the $ 3 a^2 b s^2$ should be killing the second term? I am not seeing how that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly simpler case you can work from, suppose the polynomial in the exponential is $p(s) = a_1s + a_2s^2 + s^3$ and that you want to find a change of variable $t = s + c$ such that $A_0 + A_3t^3/3 - zt = p(s)$.

Taking
\begin{align}
A_0 &= (2a_2^2 - 9a_1)a_2/27,\\
A_3 &= 3,\\
c &= a_2/3, \\
z &= a_2^2/3 - a_1
\end{align}
you have
\begin{equation}
A_0 + A_3t^3/3 - zt = a_1s + a_2s^2 + s^3.
\end{equation}
The term $A_0$ can be factored out of the exponential.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. There is one step I don't understand. This transformation gives me $A_0 + \frac{A_3t^3}{3} -zt=A_0 + t^3 -zt$ but how do I get rid of the $A_3$ but keeping the $\frac{1}{3}$? I want to have something like $A_0 + \frac{t^3}{3} -zt$ I am not seeing this.

Comment: I think I figured it out, it is just another change of variable $t\to 3^{-1/3}t$.

Comment: Unfortunately I just noticed that this gives me the Airy function at the position $\frac{z(\lambda)t}{(3a^3)^{1/3}}$, which is not really the position I need ($Ai(\lambda)$). So I assume it is impossible to derive the normal asymptotics through this method. But thank you very much.